# XSLT - Group by 2 levels

Tags: xslt, group-by

Hope you are doing fine
I've a scenario where I get a result set from a service that is flat structured
This result set has Manager, his Projects and Activities in each projects

What I want to transform this flat structure in to xml that is

```
Grouped by Manager
    Grouped by Project
         Activities in that Project
```

Here is the xml that I have

```
<Results>
<Result>
    <ActivityId>101</ActivityId>
    <ActivityName>T1</ActivityName>
    <ProjectId>1001</ProjectId>
    <ProjectName>Prj1</ProjectName>
    <Description>some desc</Description>
    <manager>jcooper</manager>
</Result>
<Result>
    <ActivityId>102</ActivityId>
    <ActivityName>T2</ActivityName>
    <ProjectId>1002</ProjectId>
    <ProjectName>Prj2</ProjectName>
    <Description>some desc</Description>
    <manager>jstein</manager>
</Result>
<Result>
    <ActivityId>103</ActivityId>
    <ActivityName>T3</ActivityName>
    <ProjectId>1001</ProjectId>
    <ProjectName>Prj1</ProjectName>
    <Description>some desc</Description>
    <manager>jcooper</manager>
</Result>
<Result>
    <ActivityId>104</ActivityId>
    <ActivityName>T4</ActivityName>
    <ProjectId>1002</ProjectId>
    <ProjectName>Prj2</ProjectName>
    <Description>some desc</Description>
    <manager>jcooper</manager>
</Result>
<Result>
    <ActivityId>105</ActivityId>
    <ActivityName>T5</ActivityName>
    <ProjectId>1002</ProjectId>
    <ProjectName>Prj2</ProjectName>
    <Description>some desc</Description>
    <manager>jstein</manager>
</Result>
</Results>
```

In this, 
Manager jcooper has Prj1{that has Activity T1,T3} and Prj2{has Activity T4}
Manager jstein has Prj1(that has Activity T2) and prj2{has Activity T5}

Here is the format I'm trying for

```
Manager
    List of Prjs
        List of Activities in corresponding Project

<Results>
    <ManagerWiseResult>
        <Manager>jcooper</Manager>
        <Project>
            <ProjectId>1001</ProjectId>
            <ProjectName>Prj1</ProjectName>
            <Activities> <!--Activities in Project1 -->
                <IndActivity>
                    <ActivityId>101</ActivityId>
                    <ActivityName>T1</ActivityName>
                </IndActivity>
                <IndActivity>
                    <ActivityId>103</ActivityId>
                    <ActivityName>T2</ActivityName>
                </IndActivity>
            </Activities>
        </Project>
        <Project>
            <ProjectId>1002</ProjectId>
            <ProjectName>Prj2</ProjectName>
            <Activities>
                <IndActivity>
                    <ActivityId>104</ActivityId>
                    <ActivityName>T4</ActivityName>
                </IndActivity>
            </Activities>
        </Project>
    </ManagerWiseResult>
    <ManagerWiseResult>
        <Project>
            <ProjectId>1001</ProjectId>
            <ProjectName>Prj1</ProjectName>
            <Activities>
                <IndActivity>
                    <ActivityId>102</ActivityId>
                    <ActivityName>T2</ActivityName>
                </IndActivity>
            </Activities>
        </Project>
        <Project>
            <ProjectId>1002</ProjectId>
            <ProjectName>Prj2</ProjectName>
            <Activities>
                <IndActivity>
                    <ActivityId>105</ActivityId>
                    <ActivityName>T5</ActivityName>
                </IndActivity>
            </Activities>
        </Project>
    </ManagerWiseResult>
</Results>
```

I'm trying to figure out a solution, but could not.
Experts, would you please help me in this regard.

Thanks in Advance,
Ravi

Comment: Are you restricted to using XSLT 1.0? Or can you use the facilities of 2.0?

Comment: I can use XSLT 2.0.
Would you mind looking at my comments below and help me out with 2.0 syntax. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a solution based on **"Muenchian grouping"**.

Try this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet  version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" />

    <xsl:key name="kmanager" match="Result" use="manager" />
    <xsl:key name="kmanager_prj" match="Result" use="concat(manager,'#',ProjectId )" />

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Result">
        <IndActivity>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ActivityId" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ActivityName" />
        </IndActivity>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Result" mode="project">
        <Project>
            <xsl:copy-of select="ProjectId"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="ProjectName"/>

            <Activities>
                <xsl:for-each select="key( 'kmanager_prj', concat(manager,'#',ProjectId ))">    
                    <xsl:apply-templates  select="."/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Activities>

        </Project>
    </xsl:template>


        <xsl:template match="Result" mode="manager">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="customer | jobType" />
            <ManagerWiseResult>
                <Manager>
                    <xsl:value-of select="manager"/>
                </Manager>
                <xsl:apply-templates mode="project"
            select="//Result[
                generate-id()= 
                generate-id(
                    key( 'kmanager_prj',
                            concat (current()/manager,'#', ProjectId )
                        ) [1])]"  />            
            </ManagerWiseResult>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates  mode="manager"
        select="//Result[
                generate-id()= 
                generate-id(
                    key( 'kmanager',
                            manager 
                        ) [1])]"  />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which will generate this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Results>
    <ManagerWiseResult>
        <Manager>jcooper</Manager>
        <Project>
            <ProjectId>1001</ProjectId>
            <ProjectName>Prj1</ProjectName>
            <Activities>
                <IndActivity>
                    <ActivityId>101</ActivityId>
                    <ActivityName>T1</ActivityName>
                </IndActivity>
                <IndActivity>
                    <ActivityId>103</ActivityId>
                    <ActivityName>T3</ActivityName>
                </IndActivity>
            </Activities>
        </Project>
        <Project>
            <ProjectId>1002</ProjectId>
            <ProjectName>Prj2</ProjectName>
            <Activities>
                <IndActivity>
                    <ActivityId>104</ActivityId>
                    <ActivityName>T4</ActivityName>
                </IndActivity>
            </Activities>
        </Project>
    </ManagerWiseResult>
    <ManagerWiseResult>
        <Manager>jstein</Manager>
        <Project>
            <ProjectId>1002</ProjectId>
            <ProjectName>Prj2</ProjectName>
            <Activities>
                <IndActivity>
                    <ActivityId>102</ActivityId>
                    <ActivityName>T2</ActivityName>
                </IndActivity>
                <IndActivity>
                    <ActivityId>105</ActivityId>
                    <ActivityName>T5</ActivityName>
                </IndActivity>
            </Activities>
        </Project>
    </ManagerWiseResult>
</Results>
```

Attention: But this does not match to your statement:

*In this, Manager jcooper has Prj1{that has Activity T1,T3} and Prj2{has Activity T4} Manager jstein has Prj1(that has Activity T2) and prj2{has Activity T5}*

Comment: Glad I could help. If this was what you are looking for please mark the answer as valid.

Comment: Hi

This is awesome! Works like a charm, Thanks very much.
Would you mind helping me out with XSLT 2.0 syntax, I've done this but this, giving only a part result, prj wise seggregation not hapenning for me. I wanted to paste my XSL here, but it is not allowing me to do it as I could answer my qn. only after 8 hrs, and comments section is too little. I'll paste my XSLT in comments one after the other.

Comment: <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="activities-by-reviewer" match="Result" use="manager" />
    <xsl:template match="Results">
    <Projects>
     <xsl:for-each select="Result[count(. | key('activities-by-reviewer', manager)[1]) = 1]">
      <xsl:sort select="manager" />
      <Project>
       <Manager><xsl:value-of select="manager" /></Manager>
       <ProjectId><xsl:value-of select="ProjectId" /></ProjectId>
       <ProjectName><xsl:value-of select="ProjectName" /></ProjectName>

Comment: <Activities>
        <xsl:for-each select="key('activities-by-reviewer', manager)">
         <xsl:sort select="ActivityId" />
         <Activity>
          <ActivityId><xsl:value-of select="ActivityId" /></ActivityId>
          <ActivityName><xsl:value-of select="ActivityName" /></ActivityName>
         </Activity>
        </xsl:for-each>
       </Activities>
      </Project>
     </xsl:for-each>
    </Projects>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: And Just one more thing, You have noted that my statement does not match wit hthe result, but it exactly matches with your solution. Am I missing something here.

Comment: Sorry I'm not really familiar with xlst 2.0. also it is really hard to read the stylesheet form an commnent. Please edit your question or (perhaps even better) create an new one.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible XSLT 2.0 solution.

**When this XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
   <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

   <xsl:key name="kResultByManager" match="Result" use="manager"/>

   <xsl:template match="/*">
     <Results>
       <xsl:for-each-group
         select="*/manager"
         group-by=".">
         <ManagerWiseResult>
           <Manager>
             <xsl:value-of select="."/>
           </Manager>
           <xsl:for-each-group
             select="key('kResultByManager', current-grouping-key())"
             group-by="ProjectId">
             <Project>
               <xsl:copy-of select="ProjectId|ProjectName"/>
                 <Activities>
                   <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                     <IndActivity>
                       <xsl:copy-of select="ActivityId|ActivityName"/>
                     </IndActivity>
                   </xsl:for-each>
                 </Activities>
               </Project>
             </xsl:for-each-group>
           </ManagerWiseResult>
         </xsl:for-each-group>
       </Results>
       </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**...is applied against the provided XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Results>
  <Result>
    <ActivityId>101</ActivityId>
    <ActivityName>T1</ActivityName>
    <ProjectId>1001</ProjectId>
    <ProjectName>Prj1</ProjectName>
    <Description>some desc</Description>
    <manager>jcooper</manager>
  </Result>
  <Result>
    <ActivityId>102</ActivityId>
    <ActivityName>T2</ActivityName>
    <ProjectId>1002</ProjectId>
    <ProjectName>Prj2</ProjectName>
    <Description>some desc</Description>
    <manager>jstein</manager>
  </Result>
  <Result>
    <ActivityId>103</ActivityId>
    <ActivityName>T3</ActivityName>
    <ProjectId>1001</ProjectId>
    <ProjectName>Prj1</ProjectName>
    <Description>some desc</Description>
    <manager>jcooper</manager>
  </Result>
  <Result>
    <ActivityId>104</ActivityId>
    <ActivityName>T4</ActivityName>
    <ProjectId>1002</ProjectId>
    <ProjectName>Prj2</ProjectName>
    <Description>some desc</Description>
    <manager>jcooper</manager>
  </Result>
  <Result>
    <ActivityId>105</ActivityId>
    <ActivityName>T5</ActivityName>
    <ProjectId>1002</ProjectId>
    <ProjectName>Prj2</ProjectName>
    <Description>some desc</Description>
    <manager>jstein</manager>
  </Result>
</Results>
```

**...the wanted result is produced:**

```
<Results>
  <ManagerWiseResult>
    <Manager>jcooper</Manager>
    <Project>
      <ProjectId>1001</ProjectId>
      <ProjectName>Prj1</ProjectName>
      <Activities>
        <IndActivity>
          <ActivityId>101</ActivityId>
          <ActivityName>T1</ActivityName>
        </IndActivity>
        <IndActivity>
          <ActivityId>103</ActivityId>
          <ActivityName>T3</ActivityName>
        </IndActivity>
      </Activities>
    </Project>
    <Project>
      <ProjectId>1002</ProjectId>
      <ProjectName>Prj2</ProjectName>
      <Activities>
        <IndActivity>
          <ActivityId>104</ActivityId>
          <ActivityName>T4</ActivityName>
        </IndActivity>
      </Activities>
    </Project>
  </ManagerWiseResult>
  <ManagerWiseResult>
    <Manager>jstein</Manager>
    <Project>
      <ProjectId>1002</ProjectId>
      <ProjectName>Prj2</ProjectName>
      <Activities>
        <IndActivity>
          <ActivityId>102</ActivityId>
          <ActivityName>T2</ActivityName>
        </IndActivity>
        <IndActivity>
          <ActivityId>105</ActivityId>
          <ActivityName>T5</ActivityName>
        </IndActivity>
      </Activities>
    </Project>
  </ManagerWiseResult>
</Results>
```

Comment: Thanks very much, its working
How do I tag a particular answer as correct?

Comment: All you have to do is click the checkmark at the top left of my answer.